# multiple data store temporary and show data row wise through JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to store multiple data temporary and also show the temporary data in a table row wise after clicking Add button, my code is below, i also add a image for better understanding[image],My Form Format how can i do this through JSON . please help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title></title>

</head>

<body>
<div>New Invoice</div>

<br />
<p></p>

<form name="" action="" method="post">
<table width="1112" border="0">
<tr><td><font size="-1">Products/Services</font></td>
<td><font size="-1">Description</font></td>
<td><font size="-1">UoM</font></td>
<td><font size="-1">QTY</font></td>
<td><font size="-1">Unit Price</font></td>
<td><font size="-1">Discount (%) </font></td>
<td><font size="-1">Tax</font></td>
<td><font size="-1">Action</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="Pro/serv" id="pro_serv">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="" ><font size="-1">Add New Product</font></option>

<option value="Development"><font size="-1">Development</font></option>
<option value="Maintance"><font size="-1">Maintance</font></option>

</select>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" value=""  /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="umo" onchange="validate_func()" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="qty" style="height:16px; width:34px;" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice"  value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="discount" onchange="validate_func()" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="tax" id="tax" value=""  /></td>

<td><a href="#"><img src="img/add.jpg" height="40px" width="50px" /></a></td>
</table>
</form>
<table width="1112" border="0" style="background-color:#3399FF">
<tr>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">No</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Products/Services</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Description</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">UoM</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">QTY</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Unit Price</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Value</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Discount</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Tax</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Action</font></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><font size="-1"><lable id="no"></lable></font></td>
<td><font size="-1"><lable id="pro_serv"></lable></font></td>
<td><font size="-1"><lable id="desc1"></lable></font></td>
<td><font size="-1"><lable id="umo"></lable></font></td>
<td><font size="-1"><lable id="qty"></lable></font></td>
<td><font size="-1"><lable id="unitprice"></lable></font></td>
<td><font size="-1"><lable id="value"></lable></font></td>
<td><font size="-1"><lable id="discount"></lable></font></td>
<td><font size="-1"><lable id="tax"></lable></font></td>
<td><font size="-1"><a href="edit">Edit</a><a href="delete">Delete</a>
</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<font size="+1">Total Amount</font>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What is it that you need to do? Why do you need JSON? Do you have to save this on a db?

Comment: No I do not want to save data, I want that when I click add button data moves to below the table,

Comment: I want to push row wise value in array and show this value below the table row wise

Comment: Have you tried writing some code? From the looks of it, you need us to write everything AND fix your html

Comment: yes i tried , but not run properly, so i do not put here this code